# Недостаток прав для перемещения файла с рабочего стола

Tags: c#, .net

Переношу файл с рабочего стола в папку, выдает исключение: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "Отказано в доступе по данному пути."
В файле манифеста приложения прописаны права администратора.
`<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`
Исключение появляется на моменте File.Move();
Код:

```
        static void Main()
        {
            List<string> filesList = new List<string>();
            var userName = Environment.UserName;
            string path = MainDrive().ToString() + @"Users\" + userName + @"\Desktop\";
            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            var files = directoryInfo.GetFiles(); // System.IO.FileInfo[]
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                filesList.Add(files[i].ToString());
            }
            filesList.RemoveAt(0);
            string pathTrash = @"F:\10. Trash";
            File.Move(path+filesList[1],pathTrash);
            // filesList - список всех файлов на рабочем столе, тип - string.
            Console.Read();
        }
        public static DriveInfo MainDrive()
        {
            DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
            return drives[0];
        }
```

Comment: Visual Studio тоже запущена от имени администратора?

Comment: Да конечно, искал  в интернете, везде написано что обычное редактирование манифеста помогает.

Comment: однако у меня не помогает.

Comment: Сами руками можете этот файл переместить? Или тоже система не дает? Если не дает, значит надо проверить NTFS права файла.

Comment: в том то и дело, что руками могу.

Comment: [Вот так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953240/c-sharp-administrator-privilege-checking) можно проверить, имеются ли на момент выполнения кода права администратора.

Comment: https://imgur.com/llc6yFp , отладчик показал что права есть, но код все равно не работает.

Comment: А если [вот это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821410/why-is-access-to-the-path-denied) проверить? Может с атрибутами файла что-то не то?

Comment: Никогда не размещайте файлы в корне диска. Создайте папку, а уже в неё помещайте файлы. И проблема уйдёт.

Answer (score 0):

Путь к папке Desktop лучше определять следующим образом:

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

Используйте метод [Environment.GetFolderPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath) и перечислениее [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder).

Ваш метод `MainDrive` становится не нужен.

Для соединения путей следует использовать метод [Path.Combine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine).

Почистив ваш код, получаем следующее:

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string trashPath = @"F:\Trash";

var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(desktopPath);

foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
{
    var destination = Path.Combine(trashPath, file.Name);
    File.Move(file.FullName, destination);
}
```

Здесь все файлы переносятся с теми же именами.

Этот код никак не решает проблему с "Access denied", но я не мог пройти мимо и не дать советы и полезные ссылки.